# Android location manager compilation error

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to retrieve an instance of a LocationManager class (do get some GPS related information). I have used wrote a simple class to do so, but it end up giving me an error

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getSystemService(String) from the type Context
```

here's my class

```
public class LocationManagerHelper {

    static Location location = null;

    public static Location getLocation () {
        LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) Context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if(manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            Location location = manager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Provider is disabled");
        }
        return location;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error message means that you're using a class (`Context`) to make a call that requires a class **instance**.

You need to pass a Context instance into `getLocation`, and use that Context instance to invoke `getSystemService`.

```
public static Location getLocation (Context context) {
    LocationManager manager = 
        (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    //....
```

If you're using `LocationManagerHelper` from an Activity, then you could pass the Activity as a Context:

```
LocationManagerHelper.getLocation(this); // "this" being an Activity instance
```

Comment: So to check it this working do I need my phone to active both GPS and Wi-Fi. Didn't work so far.

Comment: @MMRUser: For the code that you've shown, having GPS active should be sufficient. If you're still having trouble, please ask a new question, and describe what is or isn't happening when you run the code.