# How can I remove the error at "Context.USB_SERVICE" (Eclipse -> Android)

Tags: java, android, serial-port, usb, host

Please keep in mind this is my first StackOverflow post, so if there are some details that are vague or stated in a stupid way, my apologies. Down to business:

I am working on a project where a friend and I are using the [FT232R](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/FT232R.htm) IC to connect an Android USB host device to a device that communicates via serial port. I have a great code source where I am working from: https://code.google.com/p/usb-serial-for-android/

The following source code is our own interpreted code derived from the above to suit our own program:

```
package com.example.commtest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.hoho.android.usbserial.driver.*;
import com.hoho.android.usbserial.util.*;

import com.example.commtest.ReadUSBdata;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import android.hardware.usb.UsbConstants;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDeviceConnection;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbEndpoint;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbRequest;
import android.util.Log;

import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbAccessory;


import com.hoho.android.usbserial.util.HexDump;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView theOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edtVertoon);

        theOutput.setText("1234553242342342341243214");

     // Get UsbManager from Android.
        UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);

        // Find the first available driver.
        UsbSerialDriver driver = UsbSerialProber.acquire(manager);
```

(The above is just the beginning part of the code.)

The error appears on the 4th line from the bottom, and it states: "Context cannot be resolved to a variable". This is just a test program to gain understanding on this subject.

Before everybody lose their minds, **I have Google'd this**, and there are a few posts that helped, but none that actually solved my problem.

I rewrote the project with API 15 as the minimum but to no avail. Maybe the fault lies in the Manifest?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.commtest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.commtest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any advice would help, and again, thanks for your time guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this.

The answer is here: [Android location manager compilation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894653/android-location-manager-compilation-error)

The TL:DR is to do:

```
// Get UsbManager from Android
UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) this.getSystemService(android.content.Context.USB_SERVICE);
```

To use your Activity as the context instance.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#USB_SERVICE), the variable was introduced in API 12. Therefore, my first guess would be that you use a `targetSdkVersion` < 12. And then, this field cannont be resolved, because it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast response @MalaKa. I made some changes to my question, I hope this will give more insight.